# How to replace one punctuation with and or & randomly using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, punctuation

am trying to remove the punctuations which are followed by punctuations and I have done it but I need to replace the last but second punctuation mark in sentence with and or & randomly.

Here is the code

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <script>
           $( document ).ready(function() {
                for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                var remove_dot=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i];
                var remove=remove_dot.innerHTML;
                remove_dot.innerHTML = remove.replace(/[,|.-]+[\s]*([,|.-])/g, "$1");
               }
              });
       </script>
     <body>
         <p>hello , . are you | . why , its ok , .</p>
         <p>hey , . are you | . why | its ok , .</p>
     </body>
```

With the help of above script am able to remove the punctuations followed by punctuation mark
Here is my output

```
 hello . are you . why , its ok .  
 hey . are you . why | its ok .
```

But as I need to replace the second last punctuation randomly with and,& how can I modify the regexp
Here is my expected output.

```
      hello . are you . why and its ok .  
      hey . are you . why & its ok .
```

Comment: There are more punctuation characters than ",|.-". Do you want to do them all, or just those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("p").each(function(){
        // get the text of this p
        var text = $(this).text();

        // remove consecutive ponctuations
        text = text.replace(/[,|.-]+\s*([,|.-])/g, "$1");

        // random "&" or "and" to replace the second from the last ponctuation
        var rep = Math.random() < 0.5? "&": "and";

        // match the second from the last ponctuation
        text = text.replace(/[,|.-]([^,|.-]*[,|.-][^,|.-]*)$/, rep + "$1");

        // reset the text of this p with the new text
        $(this).text(text);
    })
});
```

The regular expression that match the second from the last ponctuation, look for a ponctuation that is followed by anything not a ponctuation that is followed by a ponctuation and then the end of text `$`. So the only match for this will be the second from the last.

The regular expression also check if there is some text after the last ponctuation (that must not contain a ponctuation). If you are sure there will never be text after the last ponctuation use this shorter regular expression (`/([,|.-])([^,|.-]*[,|.-])$/`).